# If conditional check in react jsx for empty values [es6]

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array

```
const myArray = this.props.values.students;
```

How can I display none if the array is empty?

This is what I'm currently using...

```
<p>{this.props.values.students ? myArray : 'None' }</p>
```

It doesn't seem to render 'None' if the array is in-fact empty. How can I make this work?

Comment: Check the length of the array? `{this.props.values.students.length ? ... : 'None'}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that an empty array is not a falsy value:

```
if ([]) {
  console.log('truly - this will happen');
}
else {
  console.log('false - this will *never* happen');
}
```

You can however check the length of the array, which will give a falsy value when empty (0)

```
<p>{this.props.values.students.length ? myArray : 'None' }</p>
```

Comment: Very clear explanation! Did you mean "truthy" instead of "truly"? Also, might be worth using `myArray.length` at that point, for further clarity/brevity.